# How can I access the values of the keys in this ImmutableMultiDict in python / flask?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

From my axios `POST` request. I get an `ImmutableMultiDict` in flask from `request.form`.

The dict looks like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"values":{"firm":"","infosys":"","spot":""}}', u'')])
```

I can convert to a regular dictionary with `to_dict()`and it looks like this:

```
{'{"values":{"firm":"","infosys":"","spot":""}}': u''}
```

**How can I get the values for 'firm', 'infosys', and 'spot' keys?**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
    const postData = async () => {
      const data = JSON.stringify({values: values})
      const result = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/', data)
      console.log(result);
    };
    postData()
  }, [values]);
```

Comment: Can you also post the API call that Axios makes? Something looks fishy in the URL, because Flask should actually give you something like this: `ImmutableMultiDict([('firm', u''), ('infosys', u''), ('spot', u'')])`. After which, you should simply be able to do this: `imd.to_dict(flat=False)`

Comment: I was able to figure this out with the below answer. I can update still

Comment: @SubhashBhushan i have added the axios portion from reactjs

Comment: Why are you saving it under the key `values` seems arbitrary and needless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `JSON` object that you need to convert first.

```
import json
v = {}
x = {'{"values":{"firm":"","infosys":"","spot":""}}': u''}
for key in x:
    v = json.loads(key)

print v['values']['firm']
print v['values']['infosys']
print v['values']['spot']
print type(v)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! is this something that will have to be done with ALL axios posts requests when using request.form.

Comment: Well you might be accessing the request wrong if it is coming in as a json request and you are creating a dict before loading it.  I would have to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data structure from axios to simply mirror the form's content:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(values)
```

Then Flask should give you an `ImmutableMultiDict` that looks like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('firm', u''), ('infosys', u''), ('spot', u'')])
```

You could then simply convert to valid JSON with:

```
imd.to_dict()  # `imd` variable holds your ImmutableMultiDict
```

You will get:

```
{
    'firm': '',
    'infosys': '',
    'spot': ''
}
```

---

If you expect values to contain lists, you can set `flat` to `False` in the call to `to_dict`:

```
imd.to_dict(flat=False)
```

Then you will get:

```
{
    'firm': [''],
    'infosys': [''],
    'spot': ['']
}
```

Comment: I have already showed above that I use ```.to_dict()```. I have also tried ```flat=False```

Comment: I am saying that there is no need for a dictionary like `{values: values}` to be passed in. Just `JSON.stringify(values)` is sufficient. The `values` key is unnecessary. Because you have a nested structure, your `to_dict` method returns a Stringified JSON instead of the JSON directly. Then you don't need the other call to `json.loads`.